Conjecture about some recurrent primes
I want to know if there are conjectures similar to this one, I know there is the Bell primes conjecture or Gardner conjecture (mentioned in this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number), but this one seems to be different.
A recurrent prime of order $n$ is a prime number of the form $\sum_{i_{n-1}=0}^{i_{n}}\cdots \sum_{i_{0}=0}^{i_{1}} a_{(n-1);i_{n-1}} \cdots a_{(0);i_{0}}$ where $a_{(k);i_{k}}$'s are sequences of natural numbers.
Let $(a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers. We define the numbers $R_{a_{n}-a_{0}-n}^{k}$ by:
$$
\begin{cases}
R_{0}^{0}=1,  & \text{} \\[2ex]
R_{a_{n}-a_{0}-n}^{k}=\sum_{i=0}^{k}{(a_{n}-a_{0}-n-i)}^{(k-i)}R_{a_{n-1}-a_{0}-(n-1)}^{i} \label{1}, & \text{$\forall\ 0\leq  k\leq a_{n}-a_{0}-n$}  
& (1)\\[2ex]
R_{a_{n}-a_{0}-n}^{k}=0, & \text{$\forall\ 0\leq  a_{n}-a_{0}-n < k$} 
\end{cases}
$$
where ${x}^{(n)}$ represent the falling factorial $x(x-1)\cdots(x-n+1)$.
If we substitute repeatidly in $(1)$ we find that:
$$R_{a_{n}-a_{0}-n}^{k}=\sum_{i_{n-1}=0}^{k}{(a_{n}-a_{0}-n-i_{n-1})}^{(k-i_{n-1})}\sum_{i_{n-2}=0}^{i_{n-1}}{(a_{n-1}-a_{0}-(n-1)-i_{n-2})}^{(i_{n-1}-i_{n-2})}\cdots\sum_{i_{0}=0}^{i_{1}}{(a_{1}-a_{0}-1-i_{0})}^{(i_{1}-i_{0})}R_{0}^{i_{0}}$$
$R_{0}^{i_{0}}=\delta_{i_{0}}=\mathrm{Kronecker\ delta}$, so :
$$R_{a_{n}-a_{0}-n}^{k}=\sum_{i_{n-1}=0}^{k}{(a_{n}-a_{0}-n-i_{n-1})}^{(k-i_{n-1})}\sum_{i_{n-2}=0}^{i_{n-1}}{(a_{n-1}-a_{0}-(n-1)-i_{n-2})}^{(i_{n-1}-i_{n-2})}\cdots\sum_{i_{0}=0}^{i_{1}}{(a_{1}-a_{0}-1-i_{0})}^{(i_{1}-i_{0})}\delta_{i_{0}}$$
After doing some calculations and number triangles we find that:
If $a_{n}=2n$ then:
$$
\begin{split}
2&=\sum_{k=0}^{1}R_{1}^{k}\\
7&=\sum_{k=0}^{2}R_{2}^{k}\\
37&=\sum_{k=0}^{3}R_{3}^{k}\\
\end{split}
$$
If $a_{n}=3n$ then:
$$
\begin{split}
5&=\sum_{k=0}^{2}R_{2}^{k}\\
107&=\sum_{k=0}^{4}R_{4}^{k}\\
6053&=\sum_{k=0}^{6}R_{6}^{k}\\
\end{split}
$$
If $a_{n}=4n$ then:
$$
\begin{split}
3\,389\,929&=\sum_{k=0}^{9}R_{9}^{k}=\sum_{i_{3}=0}^{9}1\sum_{i_{2}=0}^{i_{3}}{(9-i_{2})}^{(i_{3}-i_{2})}\sum_{i_{1}=0}^{i_{2}}{(6-i_{1})}^{(i_{2}-i_{1})}\sum_{i_{0}=0}^{i_{1}}{(3-i_{0})}^{(i_{1}-i_{0})}\delta_{i_{0}}\\
\end{split}
$$
these numbers are particular recurrent primes.
also if $a_{n}=5n$ we have:
$$
\begin{split}
197\,269&=\sum_{k=0}^{8}R_{8}^{k}\\
\end{split}
$$
another example, if $a_{n}=n^{2}$ then:
$$
\begin{split}
2\,999&=\sum_{k=0}^{6}R_{6}^{k}\\
2\,883\,135\,407&=\sum_{k=0}^{12}R_{12}^{k}\\
\end{split}
$$
We state the following conjecture :
$\textbf{Conjecture}$
Let $(a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers.
There are infinitely many pairs $(N, p)$ such that:
$$p=\sum_{k=0}^{a_{N}-a_{0}-N}R_{a_{N}-a_{0}-N}^{k}$$
where $N$ is a natural number, and $p$ a prime number.
Also what is the explicit formula of the numbers $R_{a_{n}-a_{0}-n}^{k}$? I know when $a_{n}=2n$ we have:
$$R_{a_{n}-a_{0}-n}^{k}=R_{n}^{k}=\frac{(n+k)!}{2^{k}k!(n-k)!}$$
I found that by drawing the number triangle of $R_{n}^{k}$ and comparing it with this one https://oeis.org/A001498, but in general I don't know how to proceed, it seems very hard.

The Stirling numbers of the second kind can be generated by expanding the operational formula $\left(xD\right)^n$ where $D$ is the derivative operator. Surprisingly, I found that the numbers $R_{n}^{k}$ where $a_{n}=2n$ which are a variation of Bessel numbers can be found in the very similar formula $\left(x^{-1}D\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k}\ R_{n-1}^{k}x^{-n-k}D^{n-k} \tag{1}$
In fact the numbers $R_{n}^{k}$ have also a formula very similar to that of the Stirling numbers of the second kind (can be found by applying (1) to $e^{x}$). So maybe these numbers with the Stirling numbers form a family, and we can consider this conjecture the same as Bell's conjecture.

You posted this earlier, perhaps to math.stack, and then deleted it?

It was said to me that it is opinion based, but now it's not, there are specific questions
